# Combining CSS Selectors with :first-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Suppose some HTML contains the following `div` block:

```
<div id="messages">
    <div>
        <span>from user</span>
        <span>The content of the message</span>
        <time datetime="2017-02-15T19:21:20.848Z">10 hours ago</time>
    </div>
</div>
```

How could I style the "from user" text (and just that text) using CSS selectors? I tried to select the `first-child`element of the child `div` of div `#messages` using `#messages>div:first-child`, but that didn't work.

**EDIT:**

There was a small mistake in my syntax.

The proper CSS selector rule should be `#messages>div>:first-child` rather than what I tried earlier (`#messages>div:first-child`). The difference is in the `>` I missed after `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a space.  You want the span that's the first child, not the div that's the first child.

Finds the first span:

```
#messages > div :first-child
```

Finds the first div:

```
#messages > div:first-child
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your div is called **messages** and not **members**?

What you're looking for is:

```
#members > div > span:first-of-type
```

```css
#members > div > span:first-of-type {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="members">
    <div>
        <span>from user</span>
        <span>The content of the message</span>
        <time datetime="2017-02-15T19:21:20.848Z">10 hours ago</time>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The first-of-type selector would allow you to do that:

```
div#members span:first-of-type {
   color:#000;
}
```